# glm::unProject to convert mouse position to 3 coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am using OpenGL 3.2 + GLM for my matrix math. Below is my code:

```
GLint viewport[4];
GLfloat winZ;

glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT,viewport);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);
glReadPixels(x,y,1,1,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,&winZ);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);

glm::vec3 screen=glm::vec3(x,viewport[3]-y,winZ);
glm::mat4 view=glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(camera.x,camera.y,camera.z),glm::vec3(0,0,0),glm::vec3(0,1,0));
glm::mat4 projection=glm::perspective(90.0f,(float)viewport[2]/(float)viewport[3],10.0f,500.0f);

glm::vec3 pos=glm::unProject(screen,view,projection,glm::vec4(0,0,viewport[2],viewport[3]));

return {pos.x,pos.y,pos.z};
```

`winZ` is correct. When I click off of the model, it is 1.0 (zfar) and when I click on the model it looks similar to what I would expect it to be. However, the returned value `pos.z` is not what I expect. When the mouse is over the background: if it's toward the center, `pos.z` gets smaller, and when it's at the screen edges `pos.z` is zfar. Can anyone explain this?

The actual issue I am having is that the `pos.x` and `pos.y` don't return what I expect ether. My model is 4.88 units wide, yet `unProject` is saying that it is around 20 units wide? (if i add the values of hovering on the left and right sides).

Oh, and the screen center is 0,0 as expected.

---

EDIT: I also should note that the returned `pos.z` is dependent on the position of the mouse from the center of the screen. It does change to a much higher number when it's on top of the model. If the Y-pos of the cursor is above screen center, `pos.z` is positive. If Y-pos is below, `pos.z` is negative. Seems reaaallly weird.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stupid question. unProject should be taking the 2d view matrix not the 3d one. Problem solved.